# GeoJson or Polyline element move / refresh posisition on zoom or drag map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I have my own map monitoring, and adding new GeoJson data for road route. It's added normally, but when i zoom and drag map, the GeoJson (road) moving like refresh the position. I trying to use other element like Polyline and it's was same. The problem is element refresh the position like dragged.

This is my map
[image]

and it's my GeoJson Component
[image]

I trying to ensure that the element not re-rendered if any state updates, and actually the element not updated because there's no state update.

I have ensuring that the GeoJson element not re-rendered because any updates of state.
Trying with other element like Polyline give me same issue, and it's happend on zoom or drag the map.

Comment: anyone has trying to create next.js app and adding react-leafet map then adding some polyline without having same issue.